# Check for given username existence in database at time of insertion in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

How to check for given username existence in database at time of insertion in MySQL in Java?

I have the following table in MySQL workbench--

```
user_id       int            not null,autoincrement
movie _id     int            not null 
movie_name    varchar        
user_name     varchar
rating        int
genre         varchar
```

Now following is the insertion into database--

```
try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/Recommendation1", "root",
                        "XXXXXXXXXXX");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                int i = st
                        .executeUpdate("insert into Table1(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,rating,genre) values('"
                                + movieId
                                + "','"
                                + mname
                                + "','"
                                + pname
                                + "','" + ratingr + "','" + genre + "')");
                out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
```

So here is I am only inserting movie id,nmovie name,user name,rating genre and then it gets into database and a user id is provided to it(autoincrement)

What i want that if i give the same name in my user_name option it should not provide the unique autoincremente id but insert all the details with the existing User_id

In other words how to check for given username existence in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the SQL to either update the values if the primary key exists, or insert if it doesnt.

In MySQL the insert only if it doesn't exist has the form

```
INSERT INTO Table11(...) VALUES(...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col11=value1, col2=value2,...
```

To specify that you want the values to come from the VALUES() section you need to make it the following.

```
INSERT INTO Table11(...) VALUES(...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2),...
```

Full example using your table and column names

```
"insert into Table1(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,rating,genre) values('"
                            + movieId+ "','"+ mname+ "','"+ pname
                            + "','" + ratingr + "','" + genre + "') "
                            + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
                            + "movie_name=VALUES(movie_name), user_name=VALUES(user_name), "
                            + "rating=VALUES(rating), genre=VALUES(genre) "
```

[MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

As a note, it's better form to use the prepare statement to avoid SQL injection.

```
String stmt = "insert into Table1(movie_Id,movie_name,user_name,rating,genre) values(?,?,?,?,?) "
                            + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
                            + "movie_name=VALUES(movie_name), user_name=VALUES(user_name), "
                            + "rating=VALUES(rating), genre=VALUES(genre) "

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(stmt);
ps.setObject(1, movie_id);
ps.setObject(2, movie_name);
ps.setObject(3, user_name);
ps.setObject(4, rating);
ps.setObject(5, genre);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks greedy What I am supposed to write after where???................Is it the constraint for User_Id

Comment: If you already have a primary key then you don't need the WHERE clause.  I just put it in as habit, I'll get rid of them to match your question

Comment: Hey Greey Thanks........But it give me error.........I Have done the following                       int i = st
     .executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Table1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE movie_Id=movieId, movie_name=mname,user_name=pname,rating=ratingr,genre=genre");

Comment: Apologies, I was typing off the cuff, the syntax should be correct now

Comment: The syntax is definitely correct, I'll put in exactly what you should put in the answer